# Engineyard Deployment: How to detect in deployhooks that its the first attempt to execute 'rake db:seed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, hook, engineyard

I am having trouble to detect that this is the first attempt of **deployment** after a server instance is booted. I need to run the command `rake db:seed` only the first time to set the default users and other details in database. I have no idea if this is possible.

can anybody help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out is by sending `--extra-deploy-hook-options` while running deployment command and check in the `after_migrate.rb` if `config[:initial]` is present or not. The command would look like

```
  ey deploy -e myapp_staging --config=initial:true
```

after_migrate.rb hook will looks like:

```
on_app_servers do
  if config[:initial] == 'true'
    $stderr.puts "Seeding the data"
    run "cd #{config.release_path}"
    run "bundle exec rake db:seed"
  else
    $stderr.puts "Skipping the Seeding process"
   end
end
```

For more information `ey help deploy`[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways you can do this.

The most simple one would be to do this in `db/seeds.rb` and query if data already exists that would otherwise be overwritten when running.

If that is done you can run `rake db:seed` in a deploy hook.
You can find documentation on deploy hooks here: https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205407008-Use-Ruby-Deploy-Hooks

Comment: actually I  know about seeding.. I wanted to know if I could detect inside the  deploy hooks if this deploy attempt is the first one so that seeding only occur when needed #bastilian